# S3; Bucket that is not public doesn't work suddently

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been working on Django project. My static files didn't work suddenly yesterday both on local and production like this

[image]

and I found out all most all files cannot open on S3. It shows like `<AccessDenied>`. I found out I can fix this by changing bucket policy. Static files do work now, but when I changed it to public, it says

> This bucket has public access
>   You have provided public access to this bucket. We highly recommend that you never grant any kind of public access to your S3 bucket.

So I'm wondering if there's better way to make static files work. Static files did work even if the bucket is not public but didn't work suddenly. I'm wondering why.

Comment: When it's was not public how was it working ? How you were authenticating ?

Comment: I don't know. But it did work completely and I never changed the setting. But It didn't work suddenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to provide links to resources in your S3 bucket is through [signed requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html).

Instead of the resources being public, they url must be signed.  Here is a fake example of a signed S3 url behind a cloudfront distribution, notice the extra query params (AWSAccessKeyId, Signature, Expires): https://kahsfkjshdf838.cloudfront.net/media/images/9fe76f4a7eaf48b3b51b65e4a4348f84.JPG?AWSAccessKeyId=MYAWSACCESSKEY&Signature=somesignaturehulcSCSS%2Bl%2FN3%2FgIc%3D&Expires=1537511748

This prevents people from using images hosted in your S3 bucket on their own sites indefinitely because the expiry time is usually quite short.  If you are signing the url's through a server you can also implement other cost saving measures such as rate limiting.

Keep in mind that if your images are being shared on social media sites you may not want to them to expire after a week, those sites will often cache the image though, so you may not encounter this problem.